# webpack grunt 2 tasks

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, webpack

I'm using webpack and grunt.

I wish to have 3 things: local-server(for working..), develpment link (for debugging and testing by half-technical people) and production link.

so far my grunt webpack looked like this:

```
webpack: {
            options: webpackDistConfig,
            dist: {
                cache: false
            } 
    },
'webpack-dev-server': {...}
```

and now I want it to look like this :

```
webpack: {
        prod:{
            options: webpackDistConfig,

            dist: {
                cache: false
            }
        },
        dev: {
            options: webpackDistDevConfig,

            dist: {
                cache: false
            }
        }

    }
```

Which ain't working...
What am I doing wrong? (or do you have any other alternative)

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`grunt-webpack` expects the targets to be the options itself. In your first code snippet, we have `webpackDistConfig` as our base configuration for all targets. The `dist` target does overwrite the `cache` property, but leaves the rest of the config alone.

For the task to work as you want it, there are two options:

1. Reference each config in their targets. Which means you would need to put the `cache` property in each of the webpack configs.

   ```
   webpack: {
         prod: webpackDistConfig,
         dev: webpackDistDevConfig
   }
   ```
2. Reference the base config and change necessary properties in the target

   ```
   webpack: {
         options: webpackDistDevConfig
         prod: {
           cache: true
         },
         dev: {
           cache: false
         }
   }
   ```